# Pear html QuickForm

Tags: php

I tried using PHP QuickForm but I keep receiving error message
Bellow is my code

```
<?PHP
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2.php'
$form = new HTML_QuicForm2('create','post','basename(__FILE__));
$opt = array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>255);
$form->addElement('text','fnane','First Name'$opt);

$form->addElement('submit','register','Register');>
$a=$form->toHtml();
?>
```

The error message

> Fatal error:Fatal erro:Call to undefined method
>   HTML_Quickform2::toHTML() in
>   C:\xamp\php\pear\HTMl\QuickForm2Container.php on line 470

Pls how can install the PEAR package in Windows.

Comment: You have to fo through this manual https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Comment: you're missing a closing quote^ not sure if is just on SO or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is pretty obvious: there is no method `toHTML` in that package. Why not use a simple `$a = (string)$form;`?

Comment: if `$form` content is string, casting it to string is not useful, maybe `$a=htmlspecialchars($form);` can help

Comment: What do you mean by that? In the given code, `$form` is obviously an object, as you could not call `->addElement` on a string

Comment: and you try convert an **object** to **string** ?

Comment: Yes, that's what the code does. Obviously, `stdClass` does not have a `__toString()` method. Just have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring where this is even documented officially - I don't really know what you are asking for?